# how to replace part of json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex, replace

I want to remove only the character "C" keys starts with C_ in the below Json String.
heere is javscript object I am having

```
var jsonData=
{
key1:val1,
key2:val2,
C_100:1,
C_101:2,
C_102:3,
}
```

I am expecting the out put to be similar like

```
var jsonData=
{
key1:val1,
key2:val2,
100:1,
101:2,
102:3,
}
```

The json string is dynamic and I can have many key value pairs. i want to remove "C_" from all the keys starting with "C_".Please let me know how to remove C_ from the object.

I tried to convert using `json.stringify` and replace but its not working.

```
var jstring = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
 var y = jstring.replace("\"C_\":", "\"\":");
```

out put I am getting is

```
"{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","C_100":"1","C_101":"2","C_102":"3"}"
```

Expecting out put as

```
"{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","100":"1","101":"2","102":"3"}".
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried and the results you obtained

Comment: @HBP - Updated the code snippet with the code snippet I tried

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have

```
var jsonData=
{
key1:'val1',
key2:'val2',
C_100:1,
C_101:2,
C_102:3,
}
```

Then you need to process it as following

```
Object.entries(jsonData).map(e => [e[0].replace(/^C_/,''), e[1]]).reduce((p,n) => ({ ...p, [n[0]]: n[1] }), {})
```

To get

```
{100: 1, 101: 2, 102: 3, key1: "val1", key2: "val2"}
```

Comment: A single reduce suffices :  Object.entries (jsonData).reduce( (r, e) => ((r[e[0].replace (/^C_/, '')] = e[1]), r), {})

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and easy to read code to do that:

```js
var jsonData=
{
key1:"val1",
key2:"val2",
C_100:1,
C_101:2,
C_102:3,
}

var modifiedData = {};

for (key of Object.keys(jsonData)) {
  var newKey = key.replace("C_", "");
  modifiedData[newKey] = jsonData[key];
}

console.log(modifiedData) // prints var jsonData=
{
key1:"val1",
key2:"val2",
C_100:1,
C_101:2,
C_102:3,
}

var modifiedData = {};

for (key of Object.keys(jsonData)) {
  var newKey = key.replace("C_", "");
  modifiedData[newKey] = jsonData[key];
}

console.log(modifiedData) // prints { '100': 1, '101': 2, '102': 3, key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2' }
```

Comment: Please consider `/^C_/` instead of `"C_"` because when the key has value `ABC_DEF`, then it will be modified to `ABDEF`.

Comment: @Aziz- Thanks for the answer. But it is changing the order of elements. Please let me know if there is a way to update elements with out changing the order

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using just `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` methods:

```
let jsonData =
  {
  key1: val1,
  key2: val2,
  C_100: 1,
  C_101: 2,
  C_102: 3,
};

let string = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

string = string.replace(/C_/g, "");

let obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Comment: This will remove 'C_' even in data strings

Comment: Using string modification methods on JSON is not a good idea. Parse it and modify the resulting data structure.